# Defining/preserving section names in Experience Editor view of component fields

Tags: experience-editor

Is there a way to define/preserve section names in the Experience Editor view of a component's fields. In the example below, each of these fields has a unique section name on the data template but they all get consolidated here under "Data" which is less clear for the content author when there are many fields.

[image]

I was able to do this for a custom chunk in the Experience Editor ribbon to access non-explicit fields (shown below) so I'm thinking there has got to be a way but not easily finding it. Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fields in sections from different templates get grouped together based on the section name. So if you have 3 templates, all with a section called `Data` - in the editor view, they will all appear in the same section - called `Data`

To keep them separated, make sure the section names are unique. In your second example, you can see that happening. You have 2 sections called `Title` and `Text` - so the fields are kept in those sections and not grouped together.

Comment: That's the issue actually, in this case those two fields do have different sections on the component data template. One for Image and One for Video. When you view this component in Content Editor you see the explicit section names. I never use the generic name "Data" as a section name.

Answer (score 0):

Working in modal dialogs for many fields is just not user-friendly to begin with. While I don't know how to change the default behaviour, I would suggest using different custom experience buttons to launch different dialogs for your different sections.

In your case, you would have two buttons: **Image + Video**

Image button would be configured to edit the Image fields, Video button to edit the Video fields.

This is probably the most straightforward way to accomplish what you want, and will have the added benefit of making sure that the number of fields shown in the dialog is more manageable.